# Is there a way to bind two data.tables by reference?

Tags: r, data.table

When I have to bind two data.tables (or data.frames), I use:

```
data.full<- rbindlist(list(data.v1, data.v2), fill = T)
rm(data.v1)
rm(data.v2)
gc()
```

This works, but the data is duplicated in memory for a moment, and this can be a huge problem if the data is too big. Is there a way to do this without copying the data?

I would strictly prefer a solution that does not involve binding the data in an external software, such as an SQL database. A perfect solution would be something like `data.table::setorder(data, id)` that replaces `data <- data[order(id)]`.

Comment: My understanding is that this is not avoidable. Note that `rbind(data.v1, data.v2)` will more or less work the same as `rbindlist` if at least one of your objects is a `data.table`, so in the case of two data.tables, the construction of the list object is not necessary. This is discussed in `?rbindlist`.

Comment: I use `rbindlist` because of the option `fill`. Is there anything similar in `rbind`?

Comment: The fill option is available in the `data.table` version of `rbind`, as you can see in the help file. as a test, try `dt <- data.table(a=1:5, b=letters[1:5]);
dt2 <- data.table(a=5:10); rbind(dt, dt2, fill=TRUE)`.

Comment: @Imo great, thanks!

Comment: You could rbind 1 column at a time, and remove the corresponding column(s) as you go to save memory.